# React / ES6 - Efficiently update property of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for the most efficient way to update a property of an object in an array using modern JavaScript.  I am currently doing the following but it is way too slow so I'm looking for an approach that will speed things up. Also, to put this in context, this code is used in a Redux Saga in a react app and is called on *every keystroke** a user makes when writing code in an editor.

*Ok not EVERY keystroke. I do have debounce and throttling implemented I just wanted to focus on the update but I appreciate everyone catching this :)

```
function* updateCode({ payload: { code, selectedFile } }) {
  try {
    const tempFiles = stateFiles.filter(file => file.id !== selectedFile.id);

    const updatedFile = {
      ...selectedFile,
      content: code,
    };

    const newFiles = [...tempFiles, updatedFile];
  }
  catch () {}
}
```

the above works but is too slow.

I have also tried using splice but I get Invariant Violation: A state mutation

```
const index = stateFiles.findIndex(file => file.id === selectedFile.id);
const newFiles = Array.from(stateFiles.splice(index, 1, { ...selectedFile, content: code }));
```

Comment: *called on every keystroke* Consider debouncing - wait until 500ms of inactivity or something before running the function.

Comment: Hey thanks for the idea but I already have debounce and throttle options implemented. I am strictly looking to optimize the update operation.

Comment: why doesn't your generator function return/yield anything? why did you enclose the code in try/catch and don't do anything in the catch?

Comment: Can you store the value that changes on every keystroke in a variable, and only update that value in the list when necessary? (Like, on user submit, etc)

Comment: falinsky it does yield however I have removed a lot of code for simplicity as it is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to construct your new array:

```
const newFiles = stateFiles.map(file => {
  if (file.id !== selectedFile.id) {
    return file;
  }
  return {
    ...selectedFile,
    content: code,
  };
});
```

Also, please consider using debouncing in order not to run your code on every keystroke.

Comment: This is a good option (and honestly I'm embarrassed I did not just do this in the first place  ). I guess there is no getting away from iterating the array.

Comment: @cbutler in case you need to produce a similar **array** with only changed one item - then I guess yes, iterating is inevitable. unless you can use another data structure instead of an array.

Comment: I was hoping for some sort of clever memoization technique but the arguments (keystrokes) are always different so I can't imagine anything better than map

Comment: Timing this doesn't yield a great improvement but it is definitely cleaner code so unless someone comes with something magical I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: @cbutler You could also try to use a real Map (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) using file `id` as a `key` and check on **your data** in **your circumstances** if it's faster to clone a Map and replace then one item by `key` directly.